# sql temp table and while?

Tags: sql

I have a table (for example) with products and second with descriptions of these products.

I've created in procedure with one temp table which contains all ID of products that are NOT in table with description. Now I want to add these all descriptions for Ids from temp table. How can I achieve this? Loop cant be I think cause it will never end.

Please help ;)

I cannot use a trigger, and I'm using SQL Server 2016.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Pr') IS NOT  NULL
    DROP TABLE #Pr;  

CREATE TABLE #Pr 
(
    [Id] int
);
        
INSERT INTO #Pr
    SELECT 
        [Id]
    FROM 
        [db].[Products] 

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Pr2') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Pr2;  

CREATE TABLE #Pr2 
(
    [Id] int
);
        
INSERT INTO #Pr2
    SELECT
        [Id]
    FROM
        #Pr p1
    WHERE 
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT [Id] 
                    FROM [db].[Descriptions] p2 
                    WHERE p1.[Id] = p2.[Id])

IF EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM #Pr2)
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product - and stored procedures and temp tables are quite vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the code of the stored procedure as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) - [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `insert` with a check that something is not already in the table.  `NOT EXISTS` can be used for this purpose:

```
insert into products (product, description)
    select product, description
    from temp_products tp
    where not exists (select 1 from products p where p.product = tp.product);
```

Comment: So I would like to insert to table Descriptions Values( Id - ALL from table Pr, Descriptions - custom added).